# Normalized 2D tensor values are not in range 0-1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, normalization, bert

Below function takes in 2D tensor and normalizes it using broadcasting .The issue is except all values to be in range 0-1 but the result has values outside this range . How to get all values in 2D tensor in range 0-1

```
def torch_normalize(tensor_list):
    means = tensor_list.mean(dim=1, keepdim=True)
    stds = tensor_list.std(dim=1, keepdim=True)
    normalized_data = (tensor_list - means) / stds
    return normalized_data

INPUT
tensor_list=tensor([[-5.6839, -7.5829, -7.2277, -6.5066, -8.4702, -7.9844, -5.6841,  1.8570,
          1.6170, -3.7592, -4.4140, -0.4981,  0.2501,  5.8463,  1.8897, -1.3968,
         -5.5402, -2.4561, -5.6819]])


Normalized result 

tensor([[-0.5981, -1.0615, -0.9748, -0.7988, -1.2780, -1.1594, -0.5981,  1.2420,
          1.1835, -0.1284, -0.2882,  0.6673,  0.8499,  2.2155,  1.2500,  0.4480,
         -0.5630,  0.1896, -0.5976]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normalisation you do does not re-scale to $[0,1]$ range! It normalises to have mean $0$ and std $1$ instead.

To scale the tensor to be in $[0,1]$ range you should subtract **min** value and divide by **absolute max-min** value.

Comment: thanks for the info